# How to separate text from the following text in excel?

Tags: excel

I have a long list of categories in the following format:-
FMCG / Food / Food Grains / Aashirwad Atta / Aashirwaad Atta 2kg

Is there any way I can get these 5 values from it in the following format:-

- FMCG
- FMCG / Food
- FMCG / Food / Food Grains
- FMCG / Food / Food Grains / Aashirwad Atta
- FMCG / Food / Food Grains / Aashirwad Atta / Aashirwaad Atta 2kg

Answer (score 0):

By formula, try in B1:

```
=IF(ROW()-1=LEN($A$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"/","")),$A$1,LEFT($A$1,SEARCH(CHAR(36),SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"/",CHAR(36),ROW()))-2))
```

Drag down

[image]

In VBA you could make use of `SPLIT()`